# Cannot Initialize ViewModel inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, android-viewmodel

Hi im using view model class to pass some data to my fragment, I have done the same using activity without having any issue, but using fragment I'm unable to initialize view model class.

```
mDriversWallet = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(DriversWalletViewModel.class);
```

And it keeps giving me error,

> error: no suitable constructor found for ViewModelProvider(FragmentActivity)mDriversWallet = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(DriversWalletViewModel.class);

It would be very helpful if some can correct me,

Comment: What are your dependencies?

Comment: def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

Comment: compile SDK versio is 28 and i have recently updated these lib also, implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

Answer (score -2):

Hi i just found the solution, just to let know others don't get me as a complete idiot :D.This project i have been worked with **android studio 3.2** and **compileSDKversion 25**.So recently i have updated **android studio to 3.6** which is latest and **compileSDKversion to 28**, this **viewModel** problem occur besause i forget to migrate my code to **androidX** .After successfully migrate code to androidX problem solved, Thanks  and sorry for such a dump question...This answer will help some other who dump like me :D